# Response from .ajax method is replacing previous contents always when button is clicked

Tags: jquery

**html code**

```
 <table border="0"  class="commentbox">
    <tr>
      <td>Some Item text
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
          <div id="<%:containerid %>"></div>
          <input type="button" class='btnReply' id="<%:rid %>" value="Reply"/>

     </td>
   </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>
      <div id="replytopost">
     </div>
   </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jquery code**

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".commentbox .btnSave").live("click", function () {
        alert("hii");
        var itemId = $(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
        var txt = $(this).parent().find(".txtCmnt").val();
        alert(itemId + txt);
        $.post("Handler/Topic.ashx", { reply: txt, id: itemId }, function (data) {
            alert(data);
            $("#replytopost").html(data);
            //do whatever with the response
        })
    });
});
```

Whenever I click dynamically created button with class .btnSave ,response is printed but If I click second time response get replaced with new value.
When I click second time response must not override. Every time response must come in new div.
How to do this.

Comment: Do you mean you want the response to be appended to the previous response? If so use `append` instead of `html`.

Comment: no I want each response must form  a new div or get displayed separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.html()` function is intended to completely replace the contents of the element. If you want to add to it, use the `.append()` function instead.